# How to clear certain amount of bytes by deleting oldest files

Tags: bash

The need is really simple to understand, harder to implement.

The goal is to create a function in bash that:
deletes the minimum amount of oldest files (that ends with .txt for example) in order to clear a certain amount of bytes from that directory.

The function gets:

- directory
- number of bytes to delete

(the actual cleared bytes number will obviously be bigger most of the times, because we delete whole files)

There is a way by doing a loop with deleting the last file and checking if we have cleared enough bytes, but I'm sure there is something more elegant and efficient.

Comment: stat the file before you delete it, take it from total.

Comment: It is not clear what will the function prefer. Older files or bigger files? Maybe the function should receive some date to know which files to filter first?

Comment: The goal is to create a function in bash that: deletes the minimum amount of **oldest files** (that ends with .txt for example) in order to clear a certain amount of bytes from that directory.